# Can print_r $_SESSION object, but cannot access it?

Tags: php, session

First, a bit of background info. I'm working on a multi-site project, 3 cities each with their own installation of a custom CMS type thing. The client doesn't want to pay out for more than one SSL certificate, and despite my suggestion won't even look into a wildcard SSL. My job is to create a unified payment gateway that sits on domain.com/paypment.php, the sites themselves sit on subdomains e.g cityx.domain.com.

Now, on the original payment page the code accesses an object created by the CMS called $_SESSION['member_obj'], and at some point in the code detects the user's account level using:

```
if ($_SESSION['member_obj']->data['account_level']==1)
```

So, this works all fine and dandy without any problems, but as soon as I use the same object on my script it breaks. I would like to point out that my code is sitting on the root domain, and the working code on a sub - I have made the $_SESSION variables available to all subdomains using:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com');
```

Now, the odd part, the object exists but when I try to use the ->data['account_level'] method, it dies on me. I know the object exists becasue I can print_r the object and I get the following:

```
__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
(
    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => Member
    [table] => members
    [data] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1689
        [title] => mr
        [firstname] => Testy
        [surname] => McTesters
        [age_range] => 18-24
        [gender] => male
        [email] => xxxxxx
        [username] => xxxxxx
        [password] => xxxxxx
        [account_level] => 1
        [joined] => 1326290317
        [password_reset] => 
        [password_reset_date] => 01/01/1970
        [last_active] => 1326881531
        [status] => active
        [contact] => 0
        [third_party] => 0
        [notifications] => 0
        [terms] => 1
        [dummy] => 0
        [override_account] => 0
        [premium_request] => 1
        [password_reset_date_original] => 1970-01-01
    )
```

followed by a load of other stuff.

So, could anyone be kind enough to explain to me how an object can exist, but not be accessible?

Comment: You need to load your `Member` class before you call `session_start()`

Comment: I was afraid of this, because the page is a separate entity, it doesn't use any f the classes - the CMS is heavily object orientated, every php file relies on another one and then another one until you get down the the base tObject - looks like I have my work cut out for me, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Could it - `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` - be because you forgot to `include` the class definition for the class that encapsulates this data?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to load the class `Member` prior to starting the session.

Check so your `session.auto_start` is set to `off` in your `php.ini`.